# Display HTML globally when function is called

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, alerts

I am trying to create a Notification Framework which can catch errors and display a pop-up when it encounters an error or if I need to throw info/warning/success messages. 
My issue is when I call on the component to display the notification it doesn't appear. I believe it's because my knowledge of html is limited.
I would like to know how I can display the notification on top of the rest of the component's html.

Also I am using ngx Bootstraps Alerts for this. the component is called from a service and everything works up until I have to display the notificaiton

Notification HTML:

```
<div class="shared-notification" style="position:absolute; top:40px;">
<alert [type]='type' [dismissOnTimeout] = 'timeOut' [dismissible]="dismissible">
    {{ message }}
</alert>
</div>
```

Notification Component Class:

```
export class SharedNotificationComponent implements OnInit {

  type: string;
  message: string;
  dismissible: boolean;
  unrecoverable = null;
  timeOut: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  displayNotification(notifType: string,
    notifMessage: string,
    dismissible: boolean,
    unrecoverable: boolean) {
    this.type = notifType;
    this.message = notifMessage;
    this.dismissible = dismissible;
    this.unrecoverable = false;
    this.timeOut = 5000;
    if (unrecoverable === true && notifType === 'danger') {
      this.unrecoverable = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I think I know the issue. It's that the html is loaded before the class is called by the function. Meaning all the values for the Alert are undefined. How can I re-set the html when the values in the class change/ when SharedNotificationComponent.displayNotification is called??

Comment: Any errors in the console when the notification should display?

Comment: No, no errors. It just doesn't display. I've tested the display on local html files by adding the alert inline and it works fine.

Comment: Where is the component imported and put on the page? It would be helpful to see more of the application structure.  Also usually for something like this it would be good to have a service that the notifications are triggered by.

Comment: So there is a service which simply calls the component when it's triggered. The component isn't imported the service is and then using the service I call the function (displayNotification) in the component.

Comment: Also, I realized that maybe it's because the html loads when the page loads and the alert is undefined. How can I update the html when the component is called and the values of the calls variables are changed?

Comment: I am going to add functions that output the values of each of the params for the alert and see if that will work. Or at least try to generate the html when a change occurs in the class.

Comment: You could initialize it with an empty value, alternatively you could have a `displayed` attribute that only paints the element if that is true.

Comment: I am sorry how would I do that?

Comment: If I call the values ffrom the store as observable will that update and display html?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to display a component like this is to take the selector of the parent in this case "Shared-Notificaiton-Container" and insert it where you want to display the HTML.